# nginx proxy static files locations for multiple web apps where static files have same relative path

Tags: nginx

i have setup nginx as reverse proxy for different web apps running on apache server:

```
/var/www/app_abc
|-static
|    |-app.js
|    |-app.css
|-index.html

/var/www/app_xyz
|-static
|     |-app.js
|     |-app.css
|-index.html
```

the app_abc runs on apache virtual host port 8081
the app_xyz runs on apache virtual host port 8082

they work fine in apache if access them :

```
curl http://localhost:8081
curl http://localhost:8082
```

now i only have one domain : real-domain.com
i can not create subdomain like , abc.domain.com or xyz.domain.com

i have the nginx config like this:

by default goes to app_abc  when request  'http://www.real-domain.com':

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8081
}
```

if request http://www.real-domain.com/xyz, goes to app_xyz

```
location ~ /xyz(.*) {
 rewrite ^/xyz/?(.*) /$1 break;
 proxy_pass http://localhost:8082;
}
```

for static files

```
location ~ ^/static {
   try_files $uri $uri/ /var/www/app_abc/$uri /var/www/app_xyz/$uri;
}
```

the only problem here is that the those requests:

```
static/app.js
static/app.cs
```

for "http://www.real-domain.com/xyz" will return 404

but works for "http://www.real-domain.com/"

my question is :

**how to serve static files for different apps where static files in different apps have same relative paths ?**